# Menu Bar that shows Evernote note list

Tags: macos, evernote

Is there a mac application that shows a list of note titles from an Evernote notebook from a menu bar icon on Mac OS X? I use Evernote for task-management, and would like a way to quickly see all the notes in my action pending notebook.